# How can I sort columns in EXCEL that are separated?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I need to sort multiple columns of an excel file that are separate. For columns that are next to each other, there is no problem because it is selecting the range (as an example of column A to C if you wanted to order the customers based on the number of operations). At the moment in which I want to order the clients according to their nominal value, when selecting the range A:D, it also selects column C, which now no longer interests me. So I need a formula that sorts the columns I'm interested in and doesn't include all of them.

I have been using this formula for the first (easy) example: =SORT(A2:C12;3;-1;FALSE)

[image]

But when I try to sort the columns A, B and D, happens the following (and I dont the column C to appear):

[image]

I have tried to avoid or deleting the columns which don´t interest me, but doesn´t work

Comment: I am looking for sorting specific columns that are separated, and formulate it in other sheet.

Comment: the results I want, are in the second picture, in which I want to have a table with columns A,B,D; avoiding the column C

Comment: Then simply nest this in `FILTER()` as I sadi, `=FILTER(<YourFormula>,{1,1,0,1})` for example. You may need to swap the comma's for a backslash within the array depending on your locale settings.

Comment: would it be a =SORT(FILTER{1,1,0,1}) ?

Comment: That could also work yes

Answer (score 2):

You can use CHOOSECOLS to make the selection of the columns you need and sort these:

`=SORT(CHOOSECOLS(A2:E12,1,2,4),3,-1)`

Or if you want it to be more dynamical:

```
=LET(cols,   {1,2,4},
     d,      FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(A:E,cols),A:A<>""),
     header, TAKE(d,1),
     data,   DROP(d,1),
VSTACK(header,SORT(data,3,-1)))
```